# TypeError: wrong argument type with Ruby &~ operator

Tags: ruby, bitwise-operators, fixnum

I try to compare flags in my Ruby application.

I have this code :

```
if self.flag &~ flag == self.flag
        return false
```

But it won't run. I've narrowed the problem to this :

```
irb(main):020:0> my_user.flag
=> 1
irb(main):021:0> flag
=> 128
irb(main):022:0> my_user.flag.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):023:0> flag.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):024:0> my_user.flag &~ flag
TypeError: wrong argument type Fixnum (expected Proc)
```

That is really disturbing since it works like this :

```
irb(main):025:0> 1 &~ 128
=> 1
```

Comment: What does the definition of `flag` look like in `my_user`'s class?

Comment: It is a column in the table User (generated with Rails)

Comment: There's no `&~` operator, `&` and `~` are separate operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `1 &~ 128` and `my_user.flag &~ flag` is that the second expression involves a dot-method call. That changes the way the subsequent tokens are interpreted.

Try this:

```
# works
my_user.flag() &~ flag

# also works
(my_user.flag) &~ flag

# best
my_user.flag & ~flag
```

You'll find that it works. This is because adding `()` or moving `~` changes the order of operations to be more in line with what you expected.

The original method call you're using is actually interpreted by Ruby as:

```
# bad
my_user.flag(&(~flag))
```

This order of operations first flips the bits in `flag` by applying the `~` operator, then attempts to call `to_proc` on the resulting `Fixnum` because of the application of the `&` (cast-as-block) operator, and then finally attempts (had that not thrown a `TypeError`) to pass it as a block argument to the `User#flag` method.

Comment: Why not simply `my_user.flag & ~flag`?

Comment: Indeed it works. I do not really understand however. I thought the columns were meant to be used as attributes and not methods. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mat see my previous comment and Jesse's answer. Without the parentheses, Ruby thinks you are passing an argument to the *setter* for the `flag` attribute in the `User` class.

Comment: @lurker Oh ok. That's because there's a setter ! Indeed, that's clear now. Thank you !

Comment: @cremno offers a more commonly seen syntax by moving the `~` adjacent to `flag`; unary operators are usually flush with their operands. I've also updated my answer to include @lurker's suggestion for alternate `()` placement.

Comment: @lurker: Of course, there are other ways one could write it but I think the one in my comment is the most preferable one ([no unnecessary parentheses](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-args-no-parens), it doesn't “pretend” a `&~` operator exists).

Comment: @cremno ah yes. If the OP wrote the expression as the operators are intended to mean, then the problem would not occur.

Comment: @Mat see cremno's comment regarding how the operators are written, which also resolves the error (it disambiguates the expression, and more properly represents the semantics of the operators). You have a bitwise and (`&`) and a bitwise complement (`~`), not a single `&~` operator, so it's more proper to write, `a & ~b`.